# Any way to parse the correct rows of date from CSV file?

Tags: python

```
temp =[(d for d in data if (d(float(["Temperature(F)"])) >=75 and d(float(["Temperature(F)"]) <= 100)))]
```

I am trying to get the rows of data who's temperature is between 75 and 100, but i am getting the error

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000.....>]
```

I have no idea how to parse the correct data from a complex csv file, and the data is originally in a string, hence the float, any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like there are some parentheses too many. Try removing the outermost `()`.

Comment: yeah youre right, i removed them and still have the same error though

Comment: Please show the updated code and the exact result you get.

Comment: That's not an error, it's how generator objects are printed.

Comment: What are the elements of `data`? `d(float(...))` is calling `d` as a function. I suspect you want `float(d["Temperature"])`

Answer (score 0):

You got that result because you put the generator inside a list. You should use a list comprehension to get a list of the results of the generator.

If `data` is a list of dictionaries that were read from the CSV file, you should be using `float(d["Temperature(F)"])`, not `d(float(["Temperature(F)"]))`. The latter puts the string `"Temperature(F)"` in a list, then tries to convert that list to a `float`, which will get an error. And even if it didn't get an error, it would then try to call `d` as a function using this result, but `d` is a dictionary, not a function.

You can also chain comparisons, so you can write `75 <= x <= 100` to tell if the number is in a range.

```
temp = [d for d in data if 75 <= float(d["Temperature(F)"]) <= 100]
```